# How to get a secrete value using aws secrets manager without aws credentials in php

Tags: php, aws-secrets-manager, aws-php-sdk

I want to retrieve value from the arn(AWS Resource Names) using aws secret manager in php. I already had the arn(arn:aws:secretsmanager:Regionxxx:xxxxx:secret:xxxxx). I get aws credentials exception when I implement in the program. I don’t have aws credentials. In Java, aws credentials are not required to retrieve value using aws secrets manager.  Is there a way to be able to retrieve the secrets value without aws credentials in php?